# How to prevent the 39352 process stuck and log continue to print for process executing worker of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: process, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I got confignode tendpoint error and I know it should be something wrong with my confignode execution in Apache IoTDB. I checked the log information and find that pid 39252 work process seems to be stuck, and this message `[ProcExecWorker-8 AbstractNodeProcedure: 39  - procedureld 39352` causing the subsequent log to continue to print. This may be the reason why my confignode went down. Anyone know why this procedure may be stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new version, 1.3.0 of Apache IoTDB has already fixed this problem. Therefore, you can upgrade your using version and see if this problem has been solved.